# magicsuggest Multiple options only in one line

Tags: tags, jquery-select2, selectize.js, magicsuggest, typehead

I want to add a functionality to [magicsuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/) plugin if more than 2 item is selected it will automatically add **+3** after 2 selected tags. or any other plugin to perform attached screen shot like tagging.

[what i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcTab.png)